# Android TextureView set scale fitX or fitY

Tags: android, surfaceview, textureview

first this is my textureView class

```
public abstract class ScalableTextureView extends TextureView{

private static final boolean SHOW_LOGS = false;
private static final String TAG = ScalableTextureView.class.getSimpleName();

private Integer mContentWidth;
private Integer mContentHeight;

private float mPivotPointX = 0f;
private float mPivotPointY = 0f;

private float mContentScaleX = 1f;
private float mContentScaleY = 1f;

private float mContentRotation = 0f;

private float mContentScaleMultiplier = 1f;

private int mContentX = 0;
private int mContentY = 0;

private final Matrix mTransformMatrix = new Matrix();

private ScaleType mScaleType;

public enum ScaleType {
    CENTER_CROP, TOP, BOTTOM, FILL,FITX
}

public ScalableTextureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScalableTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScalableTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public ScalableTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    mScaleType = scaleType;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.v(TAG, "onMeasure, mContentoWidth " + mContentWidth + ", mContentHeight " + mContentHeight);

    if (mContentWidth != null && mContentHeight != null) {
        updateTextureViewSize();
    }
}

public void updateTextureViewSize() {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, ">> updateTextureViewSize");
    if (mContentWidth == null || mContentHeight == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("null content size");
    }

    float viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    float viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    float contentWidth = mContentWidth;
    float contentHeight = mContentHeight;

    if (SHOW_LOGS) {
        Logger.v(TAG, "updateTextureViewSize, mContentWidth " + mContentWidth + ", mContentHeight " + mContentHeight + ", mScaleType " + mScaleType);
        Logger.v(TAG, "updateTextureViewSize, viewWidth " + viewWidth + ", viewHeight " + viewHeight);
    }

    float scaleX = 1.0f;
    float scaleY = 1.0f;

    switch (mScaleType) {
        case FILL:
            if (viewWidth > viewHeight) {   // device in landscape
                scaleX = (viewHeight * contentWidth) / (viewWidth * contentHeight);
            } else {
                scaleY = (viewWidth * contentHeight) / (viewHeight * contentWidth);
            }
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
        case CENTER_CROP:

        case FITX:


        case TOP:
            if (contentWidth > viewWidth && contentHeight > viewHeight) {
                scaleX = contentWidth / viewWidth;
                scaleY = contentHeight / viewHeight;
            } else if (contentWidth < viewWidth && contentHeight < viewHeight) {
                scaleY = viewWidth / contentWidth;
                scaleX = viewHeight / contentHeight;
            } else if (viewWidth > contentWidth) {
                scaleY = (viewWidth / contentWidth) / (viewHeight / contentHeight);
            } else if (viewHeight > contentHeight) {
                scaleX = (viewHeight / contentHeight) / (viewWidth / contentWidth);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (SHOW_LOGS) {
        Logger.v(TAG, "updateTextureViewSize, scaleX " + scaleX + ", scaleY " + scaleY);
    }

    // Calculate pivot points, in our case crop from center
    float pivotPointX;
    float pivotPointY;

    switch (mScaleType) {
        case TOP:
            pivotPointX = 0;
            pivotPointY = 0;
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
            pivotPointX = viewWidth;
            pivotPointY = viewHeight;
            break;
        case CENTER_CROP:
            pivotPointX = viewWidth / 2;
            pivotPointY = viewHeight / 2;
            break;

        case FITX:
            pivotPointX = viewWidth ;
            pivotPointY = viewHeight ;
            break;

        case FILL:
            pivotPointX = mPivotPointX;
            pivotPointY = mPivotPointY;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("pivotPointX, pivotPointY for ScaleType " + mScaleType + " are not defined");
    }

    if (SHOW_LOGS)
        Logger.v(TAG, "updateTextureViewSize, pivotPointX " + pivotPointX + ", pivotPointY " + pivotPointY);

    float fitCoef = 1;
    switch (mScaleType) {
        case FILL:
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
        case CENTER_CROP:
        case TOP:
            if (mContentHeight > mContentWidth) { //Portrait video
                fitCoef = viewWidth / (viewWidth * scaleX);
            } else { //Landscape video
                fitCoef = viewHeight / (viewHeight * scaleY);
            }
            break;
    }

    mContentScaleX = fitCoef * scaleX;
    mContentScaleY = fitCoef * scaleY;

    mPivotPointX = pivotPointX;
    mPivotPointY = pivotPointY;

    updateMatrixScaleRotate();
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "<< updateTextureViewSize");
}

private void updateMatrixScaleRotate() {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, ">> updateMatrixScaleRotate, mContentRotation " + mContentRotation + ", mContentScaleMultiplier " + mContentScaleMultiplier + ", mPivotPointX " + mPivotPointX + ", mPivotPointY " + mPivotPointY);

    mTransformMatrix.reset();
    mTransformMatrix.setScale(mContentScaleX * mContentScaleMultiplier, mContentScaleY * mContentScaleMultiplier, mPivotPointX, mPivotPointY);
    mTransformMatrix.postRotate(mContentRotation, mPivotPointX, mPivotPointY);
    setTransform(mTransformMatrix);
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "<< updateMatrixScaleRotate, mContentRotation " + mContentRotation + ", mContentScaleMultiplier " + mContentScaleMultiplier + ", mPivotPointX " + mPivotPointX + ", mPivotPointY " + mPivotPointY);
}

private void updateMatrixTranslate() {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "updateMatrixTranslate, mContentX " + mContentX + ", mContentY " + mContentY);
    }

    float scaleX = mContentScaleX * mContentScaleMultiplier;
    float scaleY = mContentScaleY * mContentScaleMultiplier;

    mTransformMatrix.reset();
    mTransformMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, mPivotPointX, mPivotPointY);
    mTransformMatrix.postTranslate(mContentX, mContentY);
    setTransform(mTransformMatrix);
}

@Override
public void setRotation(float degrees) {
    if (SHOW_LOGS)
        Logger.d(TAG, "setRotation, degrees " + degrees + ", mPivotPointX " + mPivotPointX + ", mPivotPointY " + mPivotPointY);

    mContentRotation = degrees;

    updateMatrixScaleRotate();
}

@Override
public float getRotation() {
    return mContentRotation;
}

@Override
public void setPivotX(float pivotX) {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "setPivotX, pivotX " + pivotX);

    mPivotPointX = pivotX;
}

@Override
public void setPivotY(float pivotY) {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "setPivotY, pivotY " + pivotY);

    mPivotPointY = pivotY;
}

@Override
public float getPivotX() {
    return mPivotPointX;
}

@Override
public float getPivotY() {
    return mPivotPointY;
}

public float getContentAspectRatio() {
    return mContentWidth != null && mContentHeight != null
            ? (float) mContentWidth / (float) mContentHeight
            : 0;
}

/**
 * Use it to animate TextureView content x position
 * @param x
 */
public final void setContentX(float x) {
    mContentX = (int) x - (getMeasuredWidth() - getScaledContentWidth()) / 2;
    updateMatrixTranslate();
}

/**
 * Use it to animate TextureView content x position
 * @param y
 */
public final void setContentY(float y) {
    mContentY = (int) y - (getMeasuredHeight() - getScaledContentHeight()) / 2;
    updateMatrixTranslate();
}

protected final float getContentX() {
    return mContentX;
}

protected final float getContentY() {
    return mContentY;
}

/**
 * Use it to set content of a TextureView in the center of TextureView
 */
public void centralizeContent() {
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    int scaledContentWidth = getScaledContentWidth();
    int scaledContentHeight = getScaledContentHeight();

    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "centralizeContent, measuredWidth " + measuredWidth + ", measuredHeight " + measuredHeight + ", scaledContentWidth " + scaledContentWidth + ", scaledContentHeight " + scaledContentHeight);

    mContentX = 0;
    mContentY = 0;

    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "centerVideo, mContentX " + mContentX + ", mContentY " + mContentY);

    updateMatrixScaleRotate();
}

public Integer getScaledContentWidth() {
    return (int) (mContentScaleX * mContentScaleMultiplier * getMeasuredWidth());
}

public Integer getScaledContentHeight() {
    return (int) (mContentScaleY * mContentScaleMultiplier * getMeasuredHeight());
}

public float getContentScale() {
    return mContentScaleMultiplier;
}

public void setContentScale(float contentScale) {
    if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.d(TAG, "setContentScale, contentScale " + contentScale);

    mContentScaleMultiplier = contentScale;
    updateMatrixScaleRotate();
}

protected final void setContentHeight(int height) {
    mContentHeight = height;
}

protected final Integer getContentHeight() {
    return mContentHeight;
}

protected final void setContentWidth(int width) {
    mContentWidth = width;
}

protected final Integer getContentWidth() {
    return mContentWidth;
}

}
```

now all the scale type fill , top , bottom ... not shown all video size its crop part from Video when i play it i just try to add scale type `FITX` for show all video no cropping

i try this for crop in Fit X

```
 case FITX:
 double aspectRatio = (double) viewHeight / viewWidth;

 float newWidth, newHeight;
    if (viewHeight > (int) (viewWidth* aspectRatio)) {

        newWidth = viewWidth;
        newHeight = (int) (viewWidth* aspectRatio);
    } else {
        // limited by short height; restrict width
        newWidth = (int) (viewHeight/ aspectRatio);
        newHeight = viewHeight;
    }

     pivotPointX = newWidth ;
     pivotPointY = newHeight ;
    break;
```

but its like scale BOTTOM or TOP i don't know how to solve it complicated to me

NOTE ** FITX added by me in code